# Salesforce "Record is not createable INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS" error

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Hi,

I'm trying to create a lightning component to add records to the campaign object and I keepo getting an error message that I can't seem to find sufficient information on.

I'm using the lightning:recordEditForm component and because it automatically generates the picklist or input field based on the field data type and doesn't need a controller.
[Here is the code I have written.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgcDT.png)

When I try to add the component to the appropriate page I get the [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmNUc.jpg) shown in red.

Has anyone else solved a similar problem?
I'm inclined to believe it's a permissions issue but I'm not sure. If there's any more information I can give let me know.

I would really appreciate some assistance.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that your **Profile** has all necessary **Object Permissions** for Campaign Object.

Answer (score 0):

For Campaigns: check if you have enabled "Marketing User" checkbox in the relevant User's profile.
This is one of annoying Salesforce Gotchas.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the user has access to create the record.
Try checking it in Profiles --> Campaign --> make sure Read, Create, Edit are checked (True)

Also make sure you have enabled Marketing User (Setup --> Users)